# What does a Profit Factor of 70 translate to in a Rogue Trader Game?

Tags: rogue-trader

70 is the equivalent of a Wealthy Rogue Trader. Nevertheless I want to get a feel or understanding of what it would mean for a Rogue Trader on the right side of the Imperium.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Mechanically, profit factor represents the probability that a PC (which is to say, a member of the Rogue Trader's coterie) can afford to buy something and maintain it indefinitely.** The rules for this can be found on page 271 of the rules.

A profit factor of 70 is enough to 100% reliably afford a single lascarbine of standard make and all the ammo it'll ever need, a copy of Mefonte's Orthodoxy, a servoskull, a vox implant, or enough truncheons or backbacks for a whole company of mercenaries.

But talking in terms of what you can afford is misleading, because **the real answer to "what does it mean to be a wealthy rogue trader" is *wealth beyond the dreams of avarice.*** It represents being richer than most planet-ruling nobles, more liquid than planet-bound merchant princes. This wealth isn't just a giant pile of gold that you sit on, either - it's tied up in countless ventures, investments, and compacts that stretch across the imperium and generate even *more* wealth on an ongoing basis, until the coins pour in faster than you can count.

Granted, the coins also pour out again. Ventures, investments, and compacts don't pay for themselves, and the complexities of the sprawling universe mean that profits don't always pour in exactly when you need them - and as a result, a rogue trader can't *always* afford everything they want *immediately,* not without having to sacrifice business opportunities or sell off profit-generating important assets. This is why it's possible to fail acquisition rolls even with all that wealth, and why it's possible to overstretch profit factor.

Still, keep it in mind: Rogue traders with profit factor 70 aren't just rich, they're *Richie Rich* rich, and are assumed to live lives of unimaginable luxury unless stated otherwise.

Comment: Somewhere between Bruce Wayne and Scrooge McDuck, perhaps?

Comment: @Kyyshak no, far more. Neither of those two could *buy a planet*

Comment: Think "Richer than T'Challa". He is worth about 50 times more than Wayne and Stark **combined**, and 20 times more than [places 2 to 25 of the richest comic heroes](https://www.cbr.com/richest-comic-characters-ranked/) **jointly**. Note that Richie rich is not even worth a tenth of Tony Stark...

Comment: @Trish I'm pretty sure the figures in that article are mostly made up out of whole cloth - I wouldn't take them too seriously.

In any case, the "Richie Rich rich" line was meant to be a tongue-in-cheek way of indicating rogue traders have the kind of absurd wealth occasionally depicted in caricature, not to suggest they literally have equivalent net worth to that character.